# Search box visual glitch

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

The corners of the search box (After the redesign) looks weird on Chrome 10/OS X:
[image]

Comment: confirmed I see it too in Chrome 10 / Win

Comment: This is a known problem, but I thought the Chrome team has fixed it. But apparently it hasn't. http://paulirish.com/2011/chrome-inset-box-shadow-bug-fixed/ I'll look into other solutions. If the css method fails, I'll remove it and use a bg image instead.

Comment: @Jin Yes, I was looking at your twitter post. According to that, it *should* be already fixed in our versions. (it reports 10.0.628.0) as the fixed version, and latest stable (Mac) is 10.0.648.204, which should be newer? :S

Comment: @M I'm waiting for a response from Paul Irish(who originally reported the fix) on Twitter http://bit.ly/dEzo2V I may have to use a bg image instead until this is REALLY fixed. I've been avoiding using an image because that's an extra server request...

Comment: @Jin I have experimented with the "fix" but couldn't make it work. However, you should *never* trust me on CSS stuff. C#? Objective-C? Yes. CSS? no ;)

Comment: Can anyone comment on whether this is fixed or reproduced?

Comment: It's fixed (at least in the lastest chrome version at the time) Version 29.0.1547.76

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to status declined this since we're on Chrome 29 now and that visual element is long gone from Chrome's chrome.